# Orthogonal Vectors Not Plotting Orthogonally (PCA in Python)

Tags: python, matplotlib, pca

I'm trying to implement PCA in Python, but when I go to annotate my figure with the principal axes, it appears that my vectors are not orthogonal.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt 
import scipy.linalg as LA

N = 1000
xTrue = np.linspace(0, 1000, N)
yTrue = 4 * xTrue
xData = xTrue + np.random.normal(0, 100, N)
yData = yTrue + np.random.normal(0, 100, N)
xData = np.reshape(xData, (N, 1))
yData = np.reshape(yData, (N, 1))
Data = np.hstack((xData, yData))

C = np.cov(Data, rowvar = False)
e_vals, e_vecs = LA.eig(C)
e_vals = np.real(e_vals)
e_vecs = -e_vecs

avg = (1/Data.shape[0] )*sum(Data, 0)

arrowprops = dict(arrowstyle = '->', linewidth = 3, shrinkA = 0, shrinkB = 0, color = 'r')
plt.scatter(Data[:,0], Data[:,1])
plt.title("Principal Component Analysis Example: Linear Data")
for i in [0,1]:
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.annotate('', avg + np.sqrt(e_vals[i])*e_vecs[:,i], avg, arrowprops = arrowprops)
```

I can verify that my eigenvectors are orthogonal by showing that `np.matmul(e_vecs, e_vecs.T)` is roughly an identity matrix.  However the image I get is the following:

[image]

Clearly the vectors are not orthogonal in the image, but it doesn't make sense why they aren't since translating them via the vector `avg` shouldn't have eliminated this property.  Anyone know what's wrong with this?  Is this a scaling issue or am I missing some important parameter?

Comment: Are you sure the vectors are 2-component? The drawn vectors could be orthogonal in 3D space...

Comment: @WilliamMiller I’m not convinced that’s the case.  The data only has two components, and the corresponding covariance matrix is 2x2.  I understand how that could happen if I started with a 3x3 problem and then tried to incorrectly project onto some plane, but that’s not what’s happening here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The vectors are mutually orthogonal, but when you plot them they do not appear orthogonal due to the scale of the plot (the x-axis range is much smaller than the y-axis range). This becomes clear if the aspect of the plot is set to `'eqaul'` via [`matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect`](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.axes.Axes.set_aspect.html):

```py
for i in [0,1]:
    ax = plt.gca()
    ax.set_aspect('equal')
    ax.annotate('', avg + np.sqrt(e_vals[i])*e_vecs[:,i], avg, arrowprops = arrowprops)
```

[image]

You can of course reverse the scaling for the vectors to force them to be visually orthogonal on a set of axis for which the aspect is non-equal, but that ultimately would not be representative of the actual data. I would recommend either setting the aspect to  `'equal'` using `set_aspect('equal')` as above or simply noting that the vectors are orthogonal but don't plot orthogonally due to the aspect of the plot.

Comment: Thanks for this.  I suppose I was getting lost because the variables I am working with are scaled very differently, so it's actually not all that favorable viewing them on equal axes.  I just wanted to make sure I wasn't losing my mind and plotting things incorrectly.

Comment: @Mnifldz No problem, glad I could confirm it was a result of the scaling for you